# Custom titleFormat for week view in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm trying to upgrading fullCalendar from 1.6 to 3.0

Previously my titleFormat was :

```
titleFormat: {
    month: "MMMM yyyy",
    week: "'Week from 'd [MMMM] { 'to' d MMMM  yyyy}",
    day: "dddd d MMMM yyyy"
},
```

Now I use the view specific options as describe in the [titleFormat documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/) :

```
    views: {
        month: {
            titleFormat: "MMMM YYYY",                  
        },
        week: {
            columnFormat: "dddd d",            
        },
        day: {
            titleFormat: "dddd d MMMM YYYY",
            columnFormat: "dddd d",           
        }
    },
```

But I can't reproduce the same text for the week. Indeed, according to the `formatRange` documentation:

> FullCalendar will intelligently use it to format both dates with a dash in between.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer on [github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3443)

> possible with the momentjs literal text formatting (with the [ ]
>   commands) as well as the undocumented titleRangeSeparator setting:
>
> ```
> views: {
>   week: {
>     titleFormat: '[Week from] D MMMM YYYY',
>     titleRangeSeparator: ' to ',
>   }
> },
> ```
>
> http://jsbin.com/nuruxizuli/1/edit?js,output